# Feed Me relative paths

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

I recently started a new Craft 3 project and am having some trouble with Feed Me. I haven't had this problem in the past with Craft 2.

The Feed URL I'm using is giving me this error:

`Unable to reach assets/data/clients.xml. Message: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: assets (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

When I try to use the siteUrl it seems like that isn't resolving either:

`Unable to reach {siteUrl}assets/data/clients.xml. Message: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: %7BsiteUrl%7Dassets (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

The file exists at that location and is accessible through the browser.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in [3.0.0-beta.10](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/releases/tag/3.0.0-beta.10). Additionally, there's no longer the concept of environment variables in Craft, instead we now have aliases. So instead of using:

`{siteUrl}assets/data/clients.xml`

Use:

`@web/assets/data/clients.xml`